Finding the angular size of a galaxy cluster when given the RA and Dec cordinates of all the galaxies in the cluster
I have the RA  and Dec values of all the galaxies in a cluster and I need to find its angular size. I do not know how to calculate it

One method would be to compute the angles between every one and use the largest angle.  Here is an algorithm for computing the angle between RA/Dec points: https://www.celestialprogramming.com/snippets/anglebetweenpoints.html

What is the purpose of getting the radius? There are several cluster radii in use scientifically: Devaucouleur’s Law $R_e, R_{virial}, R_{200}, R_{200\Omega_m^{-1}}$, Harmonic Radius, etc.  Are all background galaxies removed?

If the cluster is symmetric take the difference in declination between the galaxies with the highest and lowest declinations$^{*}$. This is the angular size.
$*$ Assuming the cluster does not span the celestial north or south pole.


assuming the cluster doesn't cross one of the poles.

